# Fluid Images with Parallax, Max-Width Trick Not Working As Intended

Tags: jquery, css, parallax

I'm building a Parallax site using the instructions in this tutorial: http://f6design.com/journal/2011/08/06/build-a-parallax-scrolling-website-interface-with-jquery-and-css/

The demo version of the tutorial is here: http://f6design.com/projects/parallax-scrolling/

I don't see the need to include my own code, because I think I'm simply missing a large concept of "**fluid images**"...from what I understand, images can be made liquid simply by adding a "`max-width:100%`" to all images on a page. so `img {max-width:100%}` .Now this should in theory should work as long as the width doesn't exceed the **width** of its container...

So going back to the example of: http://f6design.com/projects/parallax-scrolling/ ...why is it that adding a "`max-width:100%`" to images doesn't result in fluid images?

Am I missing a basic concept here?

You can see an example site I'm building here: http://alvarenga.co/liquid/index.html

Essentially, as you shrink down the page--the snake, and also parallaxing background elements would also shrink proportionally...hence then need for fluid images.

Thanks in advanced...

Comment: I'm not really understanding your question. What are you trying to accomplish? I've never heard of "liquid images." Do you want images that resize as the fluid parent container changes size? Also, you should post some code to help us understand what is and/or isn't working as expected.

Comment: Liquid Images are displayed here: http://unstoppablerobotninja.com/demos/resize/

I guess the proper term is "fluid"...so I apologize for that, I'll be sure to edit the post title to reflect that...

Here is my example page: http://alvarenga.co/liquid/index.html ...essentially I want to make it so when you shrink the browser window--the image of the snake (and the parallaxing background images) shrink proportionally...

Comment: afaik images themselves never change size automatically (and fluidly) when the size of the window changes. Fluid is layout, i.e. things can move underneath each other when window resized.

Comment: That generally makes sense, but why does this example: http://unstoppablerobotninja.com/demos/resize/ behave in that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more complicated than just using `max-width`. To get your parallax images to resize with the viewport (browser window), without extending beyond their natural size, try this:

```
#parallax-bg3 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 3;
}
#bg3-1 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1920px;
    position: relative;
    top: -111px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The CSS above is for your example code (HTML), specifically. Basically, this is what's happening:

- You have a container div `#parallex-bg3` which has a fluid width `100%`.
- You have an image `#bg3-1` within the container `div` that has a fluid width of `100%` and a `max-width` equal to the image's natural width. Additionally, you have `margin: 0 auto` to center the image *(once the image reaches its maximum width, it would otherwise be left-aligned in the container div)*.

When the viewport resizes, the div resizes to fill the window 100%, and then the image is also going to resize to fill the div 100%. The div and image will never grow beyond `1920px`, so your image won't get too big. Really, you don't need to set the `max-width` on the image, just the container `div`. I added it for good measure. But if the container div will never get larger than 1920px, then the image won't either (since its width is 100%).

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! This now makes perfect sense to me!

I guess I was confused with the whole concept. So the image is actually acting fluid based on a parent div class width and not the actual viewport...

Comment: I updated my answer. The changes will keep the image centered should the viewport ever get wider than 1920px. Also, there was no need for `max-width` on the div.